# How to search entire hard drive for a specific file (Java Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, scanning

```
    public static void fileSearcher() throws IOException {
    File dire = new File ("C:/");
    String[] allFile = dire.list();
    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {            
        String FilIn = allFile[i];                   // here is where I need to scan entire pc for file
        if(FilIn.equals("eclipse.exe")){
            System.out.println("Found Eclipse!");
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Eclipse not found on local drive.");
        }
```

Is there a simple way to scan an entire HHD/SSD for a specific file ?

Comment: Use `Files.walk` or `Files.walkFileTree`.  Read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) for more information.

Comment: a) you need to loop over all files, not just the first 10 files. b) use `listFiles()` instead of `list()` to get a `File[]`. c) you need to check if the file is a directory (which is easy if you did `b)`) and repeat the search process for that folder recursively.

Comment: @f1sh there are simpler ways than that ... since Java 7.

Comment: @StephenC That is correct, but this looks like an assignment that requires "manual" traversing.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job for you and it works too when there are multiple drives or partitions. It will also search for additional files with that same name.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class HardDiskSearcher {

    private static boolean fileFound = false;

    private static String searchTerm = "eclipse.exe";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        fileFound = false;

        File[] systemRoots = File.listRoots();
        FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

        for (File root: systemRoots) {
            if (fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(root).equals("Local Disk")) {
                File[] filesFromRoot = root.listFiles();
                recursiveSearch(searchTerm, filesFromRoot);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("File you searched for was found?  : " + fileFound);

    }

    private static void recursiveSearch(String searchTerm, File... files) {

        for (File file: files) {

            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                File[] filesInFolder = file.listFiles();

                if (filesInFolder != null) {
                    for (File f : filesInFolder) {
                        if (f.isFile()) {
                            if (isTheSearchedFile(f, searchTerm)) {
                                fileFound = true;
                            }
                        }   
                    }

                    for (File f : filesInFolder) {
                        if (f.isDirectory()) {
                            recursiveSearch(searchTerm, f);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (isTheSearchedFile(file, searchTerm)) {
                fileFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isTheSearchedFile(File file, String searchTerm) {
        if (file.isFile() && (searchTerm.equals(file.getName())) ) {
            System.out.println("The file you searched for has been found! " +
                    "It was found at: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I am not 100% sure about why the if-statement (filesInFolder != null) is necessary here but i suspect Windows returns null when trying to list files from specific system folder or something.

Comment: I just tried it but nothing comes up, I know its scanning the disk from task manager but nothing comes up in the end when program stops running.